# How to redirect users to the last page viewed

Tags: plugins

I am currently using the wp-members wordpress plugin. I just learned that they have no functionality to redirect the user to the last page viewed after login or registration .. which has a solution thank you

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...

```
function save_url_before_login() {
  if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
    $_SESSION['referer_url'] = get_the_permalink();
}
add_action('wp', 'save_url_before_login');
```

and:

```
function redirect_after_login() {
  $redirect_url = home_url('/');
  if (isset($_SESSION['referer_url'])) {
    $redirect_url = $_SESSION['referer_url'];
    unset($_SESSION['referer_url']);
  }
  return $redirect_url;
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_after_login');
```

Comment: hello. a big thank you I will test it and I will come back to say how it goes.

Comment: Hello
I just tried the two codes one after the other but unfortunately it did not work, there is also a brace missing in the first code

Comment: 1 ° I therefore create an example page with a link to the login page
2 ° I connect, after connection, I stay on the connection page
3 ° I am not redirected to the example page

Answer (score 0):

I use this code on functions.php

```php
// redirects user after login and logout
if (! function_exists('ctm_login')) {
    add_action('wp_login', 'ctm_login');
    function ctm_login(){wp_redirect($_POST['link']);exit;}
}
if (! function_exists('ctm_logout')) {
    add_action('wp_logout', 'ctm_logout');
    function ctm_logout(){wp_redirect($_POST['link']);exit;}
}
```

however this works because I have a input hidden on the login form

```php
<input type="hidden" name="link" value="<?php echo home_url(add_query_arg(array($_GET), $wp->request));?>">
```